# How to initialize a local struct object in C++ (cannot create a new object as a local variable)?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, linked-list

I'm learning C++ and I want to implement a simple linked list. Here is my code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};
int main()
{
    ListNode start = ListNode(-1);
    ListNode *startptr = &start;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ListNode foo=ListNode(i);
        startptr->next = &foo;
        startptr = startptr->next;
    }
    
}
```

But after running the code, I find that something goes wrong. In the code

```
ListNode foo=ListNode(i)
```

`foo` always has the same address that the `startptr` cannot point to a new node.
I switch to the debug mode, and get this picture:

[image]

It seems like there is only one `foo`, and each time I 'create' a new `ListNode` called `foo`, the last `ListNode` will be overwrite.

I used to work with Python, and I haven't met such kind of problem. It is really confusing to me.

Comment: I recommend learning from a [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Programming experience in Python is a boon, but don't apply the Python object model onto C++ objects.

Comment: Story Teller's right here, you need to get a good book/tutorial to learn idiomatic C++ from.

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocation instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ListNode foo=ListNode(i); startptr->next = &foo;`, you are referring to an object with automatic storage duration and block scope. Hence, object `foo` will be destroyed at the end of each loop cycle, and referring to it later on yields undefined behaviour.

The nodes of a linked list are often created with dynamic storage duration, i.e. with `new`. See the following adapted code illustrating this:

```
int main()
{
    ListNode *start = new ListNode(-1);
    ListNode *ptr = start;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ListNode *foo = new ListNode(i);
        ptr->next = foo;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please modify the example or add a note about preferring smart pointers over raw pointers?